# Contact list program

Tags: java

My assignment is to create a basic contact list program that lets the user

1. Enter a new contact,
2. Print the contact list,
3. Retrieve a contact by last name,
4. Email, and
5. Retrieve contacts in a specific zip code.

My idea is to create 3 classes:

`Main()`, `Contact()`, and `ContactList()`. I would proceed by having the `main()` handle the menu and the logic. `Contact()` would be a class object I would instantiate for each contact. `ContactList()` would be the class that defines an array of Contact objects, and define methods to enter and retrieve information.

The problem is I'm not sure how to go about this. Would my approach stated above work? I'm not quite sure how to go about this and any suggestions and ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This post is now edited. Please take a look at the problems I have listed above.

Comment: I believe this should be a seperate question.

Comment: @jmoreno, if you mean I should create another topic by saying separate question, I have done so and gotten my topic closed because of "repost"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would have your ContactList implement a generic list

```
public class ContactdList implements List<Contact>
```

but yeah, that sounds like it would work.  I assume this is for a class, you don't want to get too far afield of what the the teacher has asked for/taught.

Comment: No point in creating a new list implementation, how about `public class ContactList extends ArrayList<Contact>`?

Comment: @jornb87: That would work as well, but then ties you to ArrayList.  What if you decide you want a LinkedList instead?  Of course that's pretty unlikely in this case, so perhaps I'm overthinking it...

Comment: Both of those implement the same interface, so it would be an easy refactor anyway, right?  Could you parameterize the class in Java to implement a type from the parameter list?  I don't know to much about generics in Java.

Comment: @keith.layne: I'm probably overengineering it under the circumstances, but...that depends upon who's using it. If you control all of the code (likely in this case) it would probably be a fairly easy refactor.  If on the other hand, if you don't, you're breaking everything that depends upon your class. Because it already implements List, I don't see where parameterization would get you anything.

Comment: @jmoreno I meant to say *extends*.  My bad.  As in `public Class ContactList<T> extends T<Contact>`.  I have no idea how legal or doable that is with Java.  Probably not too helpful to the problem either.

Comment: @everyone, could you guys be so kind as to check my edited questions above? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts on this, with some pseudocode to help.

The following class is a basic implementation for what a contact should consist of based on the requirements.  I opted for using String fields since this is just a homework problem and requires no extra engineering.

```
 public class Contact  
    {  
        private String firstName;  
        private String lastName;  
        private String email;  
        private String zipCode;  
        public Contact()  
        {  
          //initialize all variables to empty string  
        }

        public Contact(String firstName,String lastName, String email, String zipCode)  
        {    
           //Use this.variableName to set values
        }
        //getters/setters
    }    



    public class Assignment1 //Or whatever assignment number this is == Main()   
    {    

       List<Contact> contacts;
       public static void main(String[] args)  
       {    
          //Retrieve user input
          // Execute rest of program
       }  

       void printContacts(List<Contact> contacts)  
       {
          foreach(Contact in contacts)  
          {  
                print(Contact.toString());
          }
       }

       Contact getContactByLastName(String lastName)  
       {
            foreach(Contact in contacts)  
            {
                 if(Contact.lastName == lastName)  
                        return Contact;

            }  
              else  
                  Contact does not exist
       }    

       void addContact(Contact contact)  
       {
            contacts.add(contact);    
       }


    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Could u take a look at my skeleton code above?

Answer (score 0):

I would have the `ContactList` only habe the required methods that make sense:

```
interface ContactList {
    void add(Contact)
    List<Contact> getList()
    Contact getContactByLastName(String)
    Contact getContactByEmail(String)
    Contact getContactByZipCode(String)
}
```

then you can implement that interface with, lets say, an `ContactArrayList` that uses an `ArrayList<Contact>` for the backing object.